# Is my explanation on prepositional phrases correct?

Tags: phrases

Example: My mother is arranging flowers in the vase.

'arranging flowers' is prepositional phrase and it modifies 'in the vase' but not to modify the subject 'My mother'.

Comment: No, that's not correct.

Comment: @GregLee Erm, not very helpful if you don't expand!

Answer (score 1):

No Jess, that's not correct.

A prepositional phrase is a phrase with a preposition as its head. 'in the vase' is a prepositional phrase, with the preposition 'in' at its head.

In your sentence, 'arranging' is the main verb and 'flowers' is the direct object.